# Redux-forms list to display many and redux form to edit one record. My design issue

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a React Redux component that list multiple records as in a list, that users can click on any item. The state is maintained in Redux as a array of objects. when user click on it an item is selected and state maintained so as to record (keep track of) the selected item. The List can also be refreshed to get the latest data, and items can also be deleted from the list. So far so good.
Now to edit one item in the list I have Redux-Forms. The issue is the form maintains its own slice of state [when I see the state, I see two slices one for list and another for form.] Now there is not a single source of information for the item being edited. It is on the list and on the form slice. If I update a field in form, it does not show the updated item in the list. I can hack -update with code, etc and make it look good [that I like to avoid], but see an design issue? How do I design this in a better way?

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

How to design a store, when the store needs to populate a list (using plain react-redux) and also edit one item in the list using forms (redux-forms) without duplicating the same data in the store?